# Creating a matrix of ArrayList<byte[]> and rotating it

Tags: java

So I'm creating many byte[] that I would like to be placed in a matrix, eg. 3x3, so 9 byte[] which I can then by using the methods below rotate them accordingly.

```
  // ARRAY LIST
    private static void transpose(ArrayList<byte[]> m) {
        for (int i = 0; i < m.size(); i++) {
            for (int j = i; j < m.get(0).length; j++) {
                byte x = m.get(i)[j];
                m.get(i)[j] = m.get(j)[i];
                m.get(j)[i] = x;
            }
        }
    }

    public static void swapRows(ArrayList<byte[]> m) {
        for (int i = 0, k = m.size() - 1; i < k; ++i, --k) {
            byte[] x = m.get(i);
            m.set(i, m.get(k));
            m.set(k, x);
        }
    }

    public static void rotateByNinetyToLeft(ArrayList<byte[]> m) {
        transpose(m);
        swapRows(m);
    }

    public static void rotateByNinetyToRight(ArrayList<byte[]> m) {
        swapRows(m);
        transpose(m);
    }
```

When I call the inserts method I want to add to the array in the correct position. So from 0,0 then 0,1 then 1,1 .... 3,3. So I created the code to do that with..

```
   public void inserts(byte[] s){
        if(x ==y){
            buffer.get(x)[y]= s;
            System.out.println(y);
            y++;
        }
        else{
            buffer.get(x)[y]= s;
            System.out.println(x);
            x++;
        }
        counter++;
    }
```

But It won't allow me to execute the insertion properly. Unsure as to what is the problem.

Kind of feel like i'm making a very blatant mistake, any help would be great

thank you

EDIT:

**code for array of arrays:**

```
private static void transposeb(byte[][] m) {

    for (int i = 0; i < m.length; i++) {
        for (int j = i; j < m[0].length; j++) {
            byte x = m[i][j];
            m[i][j] = m[j][i];
            m[j][i] = x;
        }
    }
}

public static void swapRowsb(byte[][] m) {
    for (int i = 0, k = m.length - 1; i < k; ++i, --k) {
        byte[] x = m[i];
        m[i] = m[k];
        m[k] = x;
    }
}

public static void rotateByNinetyToLeftb(byte[][] m) {
    transposeb(m);
    swapRowsb(m);
}

public static void rotateByNinetyToRightb(byte[][] m) {
    swapRowsb(m);
    transposeb(m);
}
```

**and insertion**

```
   private byte[][] buffer;
    private int x=0;
    private int y=0;

    public FixedBuffer(int BUFF_SIZE) {
        this.BUFF_SIZE = BUFF_SIZE;
        buffer = new byte[BUFF_SIZE][BUFF_SIZE];
    }


     public void inserts(byte[] s){
            if(x ==y){
                buffer.get(x)[y]= s;
                System.out.println(y);
                y++;
            }
            else{
                buffer.get(x)[y]= s;
                System.out.println(x);
                x++;
            }
            counter++;
        }
```

Say we have a vector of 3 x 3

I want to use inserts() to add all the byte[], there will be 9 in total. so 9 byte[], each time I add one the index's (x and y) change.

**Structure:**

```
byte[], byte[], byte[]
byte[], byte[], byte[]
byte[], byte[], byte[]
```

Comment: Why are you mixing the Collections API (`ArrayList`) with arrays? I would either use an array of arrays (`byte[][]`) or else just use one big array of `byte[]` and compute offsets into it (e.g. `matrix[y * width + x]`).

Comment: is it bad to mix ArrayList with arrays? I was originally using byte[][] but I couldn't get it to work, thats the reason I switched, I could post my code for that if you like? @DanielPryden

Comment: Instead of a question of good or bad, I think it's more a matter code readability, and/or logic. Using an ArrayList of byte arrays is compounding your issues. Why not use an Array first, get things going well, and then convert to ArrayLists if you so desire? I think it will be easier to get the logic foolproof that way.

Comment: See thats the problem @DebosmitRay that's why I turned to ArrayLists with arrays in them because I couldn't get it working. I've posted my code for the array of arrays in the edit

Comment: Let me run your code and get back to you.

Comment: `transpose(..)` and `swapRows(..)` work perfect. What exactly is your issue? I just rotated an array clockwise and anti-clockwise by 90 degrees.

Comment: The insertion of the byte[] into the byte[][], did that work perfectly for you? @DebosmitRay

Comment: What exactly is that function supposed to do?

Comment: So it's supposed to add a byte[] to position 0,0 then 0,1, then 1,1 of the byte[][] @DebosmitRay

Comment: Let me get this straight. It is essentially inserting values into rows, correct? If I pass `{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}` to this function, my 2D array will look like `{{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9}}`

Comment: if each of the values 1,2,3,4,5 are their own unique byte[] as I plan on using this for a VoIP system, so each byte[] is essentially a packet @DebosmitRay

Comment: @session_start Still doesn't tell me what exactly the function should do.

Comment: So the function should insert the byte[] into a byte[][] which is called buffer. @DebosmitRay  ( buffer[][] )

Comment: @session_start The insert operation, traditionally, has a index at which to insert. You seem to provide no such index.

Comment: yeah they are both initialised at 0 @DebosmitRay so x =0 and y = 0 , check my edit

Comment: @session_start I am not clear on what you want to do. Either you give an example, showing how exactly the function works, or I'll leave the question for someone else to answer.

Comment: @session_start If I pass {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9} to this function, will my 2D array will look like {{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9}}?

Comment: Check my edit @DebosmitRay

Comment: @session_start buffer.get(x) on a 2D array??

Comment: Is it wrong? This is my problem, I don't know how to implement this properly @DebosmitRay

Comment: I understand the issue. Moving this to an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some test code first.

```
ArrayList<byte[]> arr = new ArrayList<byte[]>(9);
initialize(arr);        
printRows(arr);

arr = transpose(arr);
printRows(arr);
```

Initialize ArrayList with random test data

```
private static void initialize(ArrayList<byte[]> arr) {
    for(byte i = 0 ; i < 9 ; i++) {
        byte[] a = {i,i,i,i};
        arr.add(a);
    }
}
```

A way to find out if all the ops are working as required.

```
private static void printRows(ArrayList<byte[]> arr) {
    int row = 0;
    for(int i = 0 ; i < arr.size() ; i++) {
        System.out.print(Arrays.toString(arr.get(i)) + "  ");
        row++;
        if(row%3 == 0)
            System.out.println();
    }
    System.out.println("\n\n");
}
```

The method to transpose. Took the hacky way of making a new ArrayList. Please change that. This is just to demonstrate the logic.

```
private static ArrayList<byte[]> transpose(ArrayList<byte[]> arr) {
    ArrayList<byte[]> newArr = new ArrayList<byte[]>(9);

    // fill with null
    for(int i = 0 ; i < 9 ; i++)
        newArr.add(null);

    for(int row = 0; row < 3 ; row++) {
        for(int col = 0 ; col < 3 ; col++) {
            // diagonal
            if(row == col) {
                newArr.add(row + 3*col, arr.get(row + 3*col));
            }

            int second = row + 3*col;       // elem at (row,col)
            int first = 3*row + col;        // elem at (col,row)

            // swap
            newArr.set(first, arr.get(second));
            newArr.set(second, arr.get(first)); 
        }
    }

    return newArr;
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't the other methods need to be altered?

Comment: Yes. A couple of other alterations would be needed in the other method. Let me get back to this question after completing some work.

Comment: Thank you, i'm going to bed now. will check again in the morning and accept your answer

Comment: Editing the answer. I did it in a major rush. Hence, the bad style. Tested the transpose seems to work as required. Please replicate for swap. Let me know if you need assistance. Using ArrayList<byte[]>.

Comment: @session_start Sure thing :)